# Summation expansion

Tags: summation, constraints

I have the following sum:

$$F=\sum_{i=1}^N p_i g_i .$$

Where $g_i$ is random variable and $p_i$ is function of $g_i$ such that, if $g_i<0.01 , p_i=0$.

On the other hand, I have (CONSTRAINT):

$$\sum_{i=1}^N p_i =NP$$

So if we have more $g_i<0.01$ this leads to more $p_i=0$ but the non-zero $p_i$ become greater.

I want to prove that with each further $p_i=0$, **F will decrease** even if the Constraint is still satisfied.

Comment: You have to specify further "F will decrease". I guess $p_i$ and $g_i$ are probabilities, $g_i = 1 - p_i$, and "F will decrease" from some starting point, e.g. from all $p_i = 1/P$. Is that what your question is?

Comment: Hi, Andreas. I have just added more details to the problem. $p_i$ and $g_i$ are not probabilities.